# MongoDB: Populate parent using array of children vs search children by parent ID

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, mongoose-populate

I'm having an argument with my manager over database structure.

We need to create a parent-type object with multiple children, and query a list of all the children that belong to that parent.

I want to use an array of child ObjectIds in the parent object, which are added when the child is created.  The parent can be found using FindById, and the child list can then by filled using populate().

My manager insists on *not* storing an array of children in the parent, but only storing the parent's id as a field in each child object, and then get the list by searching for all of the child objects with the parent's id.  He claims that this will be just as fast, since "populate just searches for the object by id anyway".

However, it seems inconceivable to me that it would be just as fast.  Isn't the whole point of an _id field to index the file's location for fast retrieval?  Shouldn't finding a list of objects where you have their _id always be much faster and more scaleable than searching the entire database for objects where a given field matches a given value?

Is there any justification for *not* using populate in this kind of circumstance?  (Storing a reference to the parent in the child object is, of course, also an option - but he is insistent on *not* storing an array of children in the parent at all.)

Comment: If the parent is going to have limited embedded documents then you should store children directly in parent. if not then having parent's id on children is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

The best method is not a simple choice, it depends on the nature of the data, what you expect for the data set in the future, and how you are going to query the data, both now and in the future.

Storing each child ID in an array on the parent is definitely a viable choice.  This makes it easy to retrieve information like "How many children does this parent have?" or "Does this parent include both of these children?".  It also simplifies paging through the children because the client will receive all of the child ID values when retrieving the parent and can retrieve as many child records as necessary for display.  Storing additional data in the array on the parent, such as a child name and added date, would mean that client could have enough informaiton to show a link to each child without needing to retrieve all of the children first.

This method also has some drawbacks.  If the number of children possible for a parent is more than a couple hundred, or not limited at all, there will be serious performance implications when the array becomes large.  MongoDB specifically recommends to [Avoid Unbounded Arrays](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/schema-advisor/avoid-unbounded-arrays/#avoid-unbounded-arrays)

Storing the parent ID in each child maintains a linkage without a single field that does not need to be an array.  This means that obtaining a list of children for a given parent would require a separate query, or a `$lookup`, but would simplify finding the child first, and then linking to the parent.
This method completely avoids the large array issues, even if the data set grows exponentially in the future.

Comment: We do not expect many children per parent, but there may be a large number of total parents and children, and we will often need to retrieve a list of all the children of a given parent.  How does $lookup by itself compare to finding by parent ID and populating from a list of stored child IDs?

Comment: If by "populate" you mean the mongoose populate method, that is handled on the client side and will use a separate find in the child collection for each child.  Using `$lookup` could get the documents in a single round trip, whether it needs more than 1 query into the child collection would depend on how the pipeline is structured.  If you store the parent ID in the child document, you could find all of the data 2 finds - one for the parent and one for the children.

Comment: So there's nothing intrinsically faster about searching by _id than searching by any other field?

Answer (score 0):

The Mongoose Populate function, while convenient, is slow - it performs a search for each child in the array.

The most efficient way of creating a database where you will need to find the children of a given parent is to store the parent's id as an indexed field in the child, then search for all child objects with a given parent. This is similar to a relational database. It is not usually necessary to store children as an array in the parent.

There is nothing particularly special about the _id field; this is an indexed field automatically created by Mongoose but you can add other indexed fields and searching for them will be just as fast.